# Loading parsed JSONArray into a recyclerView

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load the result of an API call into a recyclerView. I created a data model to hold the array of results (strings) to be used in populating the recyclerView Adapter. But once the JSON file is parsed, the application crashes on the call to "setValues" of the data model but the result displays accurately on the logcat.
    my code is below:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.limitless.googlebooks;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {
    private EditText bookImput;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private static Books books;
    ArrayList<Books> booksArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bookImput = findViewById(R.id.bookInput);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bookRecyclerView);
        booksArray =  new ArrayList<>();
        BooksAdapter adapter = new BooksAdapter(booksArray);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        if(LoaderManager.getInstance(this).getLoader(0) != null){
            LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(0,null, this);
        }
    }

    public void searchBooks(View view) {
        String queryText = bookImput.getText().toString();
        InputMethodManager methodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(methodManager != null){
            methodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
                    methodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
        if(connectivityManager != null){
            networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        }
        if(networkInfo != null && !isEmpty(queryText) && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            Bundle queryBundle = new Bundle();
            queryBundle.putString("queryString", queryText);
            LoaderManager.getInstance(this).restartLoader(0, queryBundle, this);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            if(isEmpty(queryText)){
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.emptyquery, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        String queryString = "";
        if(args != null){
            queryString = args.getString("queryString");
        }
        return new BookLoader(this, queryString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<String> loader, String data) {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray itemsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

            int i = 0;
            String title = null;
            String authors = null;
            String publisher = null;
            String date = null;

            while(i < itemsArray.length() && title == null && authors == null && date == null){
                JSONObject book = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = book.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                try{
                    title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                    authors = volumeInfo.getString("authors");
                    publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");
                    date = volumeInfo.getString("publishedDate");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }
            if(title != null && authors != null && date != null){
                books.setBookName(title);
                books.setAuthorsName(authors);
                books.setPublisher(publisher);
                books.setPublishedDate(date);
                booksArray.add(books);
            }else {
                books.setBookName(String.valueOf(R.string.no_results));
                books.setAuthorsName("");
                books.setPublisher("");
                books.setPublishedDate("");;
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            books.setBookName(String.valueOf(R.string.error));
            books.setAuthorsName("");
            books.setPublisher("");
            books.setPublishedDate("");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<String> loader) {

    }
}
```

**Data Model**

```
package com.limitless.googlebooks;

public class Books {
    private String bookName;
    private String authorsName;
    private String publisher;
    private String publishedDate;

    public Books(String bookName, String authorsName, String publisher, String publishedDate) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.authorsName = authorsName;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }
    public Books(){}


    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getAuthorsName() {
        return authorsName;
    }

    public void setAuthorsName(String authorsName) {
        this.authorsName = authorsName;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }

    public void setPublishedDate(String publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
package com.limitless.googlebooks;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BooksAdapter.BooksHolder>{
    ArrayList<Books> booksArrayList;
    public BooksAdapter(ArrayList<Books> booksArray){
        this.booksArrayList = booksArray;
        }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BooksHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.booklist, parent, false);
        return new BooksHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BooksHolder holder, int position) {
        Books books = booksArrayList.get(position);
        holder.bind(books);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return booksArrayList.size();
    }

    public class BooksHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView bookName;
        private TextView authorsName;
        private TextView publisher;
        private TextView publishedDate;

        public BooksHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            bookName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
            authorsName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.authorsName);
            publisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);
            publishedDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publishedDate);
        }

        public void bind(Books books){
            bookName.setText(books.getBookName());
            authorsName.setText(books.getAuthorsName());
            publisher.setText(books.getPublisher());
            publishedDate.setText(books.getPublishedDate());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get on the log?

Comment: Can you print the error from the logcat ? It will help us to understand the root cause properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **In your `MainActivity`:**

These

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {
....
    private static Books books;
    ArrayList<Books> booksArray;
```

Becomes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {
....  
    private Books books;
    private ArrayList<Books> booksArray;
    private BooksAdapter adapter;
```

### **In `onCreate()`:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ........
        adapter = new BooksAdapter(booksArray);
        ........
        ........


}
```

### **Now in `onLoadFinished()`:**

This:

```
        if(title != null && authors != null && date != null){
            books.setBookName(title);
            books.setAuthorsName(authors);
            books.setPublisher(publisher);
            books.setPublishedDate(date);
            booksArray.add(books);
        }else {
            books.setBookName(String.valueOf(R.string.no_results));
            books.setAuthorsName("");
            books.setPublisher("");
            books.setPublishedDate("");;
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        books.setBookName(String.valueOf(R.string.error));
        books.setAuthorsName("");
        books.setPublisher("");
        books.setPublishedDate("");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Becomes:

```
        if(title != null && authors != null && date != null){

            books = new Books(title,authors,publisher,date);
            booksArray.add(books);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }else {

            books = new Books(String.valueOf(R.string.no_results),"","","");

            //if you want to add them to array add them, if not then don't
            booksArray.add(books);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){

            books = new Books(String.valueOf(R.string.error),"","","");

            //if you want to add them to array add them, if not then don't
            booksArray.add(books);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed I didn't instatiate the Books object in onCreate. But your answervhas helped me to solve even another difficulty. I appreciate

Comment: If this helped accept the answer so that others with same problem know that this is a solution. GoodLuck.